# Advantage of GCM for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a server and an App for Android that's using GCM for push notifications, everything works well, I need to start creating an iOS app to do the same. GCM currently supports iOS: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start

My understanding with the architecture is as follows:

Android GCM:

App->GCM->App->Server (Requesting/Registering Tokens)

Server->GCM->App (sending push notifications)

Is the following correct for iOS using GCM?

App->APNS->App->GCM->App->Server (Requesting/Registering Tokens)

Server->GCM->APNS->App (sending push notifications)

If my understanding is correct, why would I use GCM as it seem to add an extra layer and possibly delays on push notifications? Are APNS limits bypassed/handled with GCM? (ie, Payload size, message storage time, no collapse keys support)

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct. The advantage of GCM is that your server only needs to implement GCM's interface for sending both Android and iOS notifications. The interface of APNS is somewhat more cumbersome and harder to work with.

Also, GCM provides some advanced features like topics, data messages (up to 4k), upstream messages (device to server), delivery receipts and so on. They might or might not be useful for you.

And no, GCM doesn't work around APNS' limits.

Comment: You mentioned GCM provides message up to 4k, I assume you're referencing Android only? Because APNs has a limit of 2k, does GCM on iOS help get around it by sending it twice or something?

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl: 1) They might just be talking about when the app is in the foreground (in which case it doesn't go through APNS and connects to GCM directly. 2) The new APNS backend using HTTP/2 allows pushes up to 4KB developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=720

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl like user102008 said, these are delivered directly through GCM when the app is in foreground.

Comment: The data payload and notification payload are both applicable on iOS & Android. On iOS the difference is that notification payload is sent through APNS while data payload is sent through GCM's own connection which is only there when app is in foreground. SO,If I want to use GCM in both android and ios,the payload should contain only notification?or is both data and notification is fine?